# java how to return custom list instead of object list in stream from groupby method?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a entity with these fields

```
private Long id;

private String name;

private Boolean isStudent;
```

Now I can group list of entity like bellow

```
Map<Boolean, List<User>> result = userList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getStudent));
```

But I am struggling to find out how can I return ID list instead of the whole `User` list like bellow

```
Map<Boolean, List<Long>> result = userList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...));
```

I can apply stream again in the another line but is it possible to it in the same line with groupby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the grouped values by use the overloaded `groupingBy` with `mapping` methods

```java
Map<Boolean, List<Long>> result = userList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getStudent, Collectors.mapping(User::getId, Collectors.toList())));
```